# Understanding sentence structure with “auf etwas Beschlag legen”

Tags: sentence-structure, ellipsis

Looking up the use and examples of “*auf etwas Beschlag legen*” on [dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Beschlag%20legen&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50), I found the following sentence:

> Bei seiner Rückkehr wurde er verhaftet, vor ein Gericht gestellt, und
> auf sein Vermögen wurde Beschlag gelegt.

The overall meaning of the sentence is clear, but the sentence structure is difficult to understand.  I think this is because there are words dropped (ellipsis).  Here is my attempt to recreate the whole sentence:

*Bei seiner Rückkehr wurde er verhaftet,* - No words dropped.  This is a passive clause in the simple past tense.

***[wurde er]** vor ein Gericht gestellt* – This is also a passive clause in the simple past tense.  Since *wurde er* is repeated, it can be dropped.

*Auf sein Vermögen wurde **[es]** Beschlag gelegt* – “Subjectless passive” clause in the simple past tense with *es* as the dummy-subject.  Since *es* is not in the first position (before *wurde*), [it must be dropped](http://www.voith-usa.com/German/Ucol/grammar/passive_no_subject_info.pdf).

Have I got this correct?

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard of the expression *auf Beschlag legen* before, and without the context I wouldn't have an idea what it (possibly) means.

Comment: Since _der Beschlag_ seems to mean "metal fittings", the closest equivalent I can think of is "to keep smt / someone in irons" (i.e. schackles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

One could argue about whether "Beschlag" is the subject in the last clause. I see how you understand it as part of the predicate, because "Beschlag legen" can be seen as a verbal expression of its own and not just *legen* plus object *Beschlag*, and that seems valid to me.

If you add an attribute to *Beschlag*, it has to be in nominative like "Beschlag" is in this sentence, so for all intents and purposes, you can see it as the subject of the sentence.

> Auf sein Vermögen wurde sofortiger Beschlag gelegt.

Other possible word order for this sentence (as you correctly implied):

> Es wurde Beschlag auf sein Vermögen gelegt.

The variant

> Beschlag wurde auf sein Vermögen gelegt.

which does use "Beschlag" as the subject, does sound a bit odd, but not totally wrong.

Comment: *Auf sein Vermögen wurde [es] Beschlag gelegt.* is wrong.

Comment: @Olafant: ... sure, and it says so in the question ("*es* must be dropped"). I think this is mostly a question on how to teach German grammar. If the "omitted es" helps to understand, I guess it's a valid teaching tool.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of the phrase *Beschlag legen auf*. Might be a regional thing. However [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beschlag) lists it as a fixed phrase. <sup>1</sup>

In your example phrase the last part could be changed to

> Beschlag wurde auf sein Vermögen gelegt.

*Beschlag* is the subject.

The rest of your analysis is correct.

---

<sup>1) I would rather expect something like</sup>

> und sein Vermögen wurde beschlagnahmt.